# need a true false answer for multiple conditions when joining two tables

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables, one is information about a `sampleid` (`sample id` is primary key) and the other is conditions the `sampleid` has (`sampleid` is not primary key in this table as it may have multiple conditions). I would like to know if my `sampleid` has a specific condition (Y/N) but not sure how to join them without getting a query that returns mulitple rows of the sampleid.

eg

```
sampleid    colour
-----------------------
1       blue
2       red
3       green

sampleid    condition
-----------------------
1       23
1       81
1       94
2       81
2       94
3       23
```

I want to ask if the sampleid has condition 23 and return:

```
sampleid    colour      condition23
----------------------------------------------
1       blue        Y
2       red         N
3       green       Y
```

Hope this is clear, every time I join them i end up with multiple sampleid- I am a newbie and trying to find my way!

Thanks in advance
F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a [left join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#join-type) and [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) something like this:

```
SELECT
    s.sampleId,
    s.color,
    case when c.condition is null
        then 'N'
        else 'Y'
    end condition23
FROM
    samples s
    LEFT JOIN conditions c
        ON s.sampleId = c.sampleId 
        AND c.condition = 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select s.*, case when c.condition is null then 'N' else 'Y' end condition23
from samples s
left join 
(select * from conditions where condition = 23) c on s.sampleid = c.sampleid
```

Answer (score 0):

With EXISTS:

```
select 
  s.*,
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from conditions where sampleid = s.sampleid and condition = 23
    ) then 'Y' 
    else 'N'
  end condition23
from samples s
```